# Passing the text name of a parameter into a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters

Below is an except from some code that I'm working on. Is there a way to pass the text name of a parameter into a function? Let's say, for example, that I call the display function using display(name);. Could the function recognize name for its value (i.e. name = Bob) and to locate the document element in line 2 as well?

```
function display(attribute) {
    var putItHere = "'show-"+ ~~~TEXT OF PARAMETER SHOULD GO HERE~~ +"'";
    document.getElementById(putItHere).innerHTML = attribute;
}
display(name);
```

Comment: Can't be done. Only values and references are passed through, no information about the name of the variable used to pass said value/reference in.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that I am more-than-anything *confused* by your question, because the answer appears to be "so obvious" that I surely must be missing something . . .

. . . and I *also* observe that there seems to be an inconsistency in your statement of the problem.  *First* you say that the `key` for "playerHeight" is "`show-`playerHeight."  But then, in the next sentence, you say that the key for "wingspan" is ... (**not** "`show-`wingspan" but ...) "wingspan."

Quite frankly, in this case I would cordially suggest that "DRY is just that ... a *principle.*"  A rule-of-thumb, which you will never find writ upon a tablet of stone carried by a now-white-haired guy who just came down from a mountain.

Even though it might not be "strictly necessary," in some abstract academic sense, "to carry-around both a key and its value," it might very well be *clearer* to do so, and it just might produce stronger(!) and more-maintainable(!!) code.  Here's why:

If you "too-cleverly" try to "avoid" carrying one-or-the-other, then you necessarily impose upon the recipient of that information the obligation to *infer* "the-other-or-one."  Soon enough, your code is littered with various bits of "clever" code that does this.  All *unrelated* to each other.

Then, "The Marketing Department" calls, with their latest hair-brained idea (which the CEO thinks is wonderful).  This idea *breaks* your "clever" assumption.

. . . and so, your team scurries around, changing *(individually)* all those "clever" pieces of code that *(separately)* "inferred" what used to be true, but which, thanks to the Marketing Department, is no longer true.

. . . and, unfortunately, your team fixes *all but one* of them . . .

. . . and, *most* unfortunately, you **don't** know it.

Somewhere, now, thanks to your "cleverness," something out there is now going:  **"tick tick tick tick tick ..."**

Therefore, I suggest that "DRY is a *principle.*"  Use it as a rule-of-thumb and as a guideline.  But, not at the expense of maintainability or clarity.  If you deliberately(!) write *one* piece of code that tells *many* other pieces of code "what they already know," then there is only **one** piece of code that must be changed "when the Marketing Department calls again."  And this **one** change will apply to all of the **many** individual cases, no matter where *("who knows for sure?")* they might be.

Comment: Do you agree with @mike-c that "no information about the name of the variable" can be used?

Comment: I have no such opinion.  (Thus, I have neither agreement nor disagreement with Mike-C.)  I generally feel that "redundancy is okay."  That you are not "repeating yourself" if a *single(!) source-of-authority* is speaking.  Because, even though "what s/he is saying is, *today,* "redundant and repetitive," it might not always be so.  In my general view, it's probably better to rely-upon the "redundancy," instead of making the inference yourself ... because: *the source-code that you use to make(!)* that inference is ... A Redundancy!  But it's a *non-maintainable* "redundancy."

Comment: There are no "bright-line rules" here.  Nothing to make our software-engineering compromises for us.  There are only guidelines and tradeoffs.  That's what makes our jobs so hard – and, so interesting.

Comment: @MikeRobinson What I said isn't a matter of opinion, it's a fact about the language. You're talking about how you should remember the DRY is a principle and thus at times can be broken but that's not what the question was asking.

Comment: "A fact about the language," yes.  But no "principle" provides a clear answer.  Personally, I look extremely(!) to what is maintainable code, and, again "IMHO," a *lot* of that has to do with how many pieces of code have to be changed "when" a business requirement changes ... and therefore, what are the odds that one-or-more of those places will someday be overlooked.  Basically, the answer to the OP's question is:  "obviously, yes."  (Like I said originally, "so obvious that I must be missing something [obvious].")  Of COURSE you can write a few extra statements to do it.